# How to open a .jar within a VB.net form?

Tags: java, .net, vb.net, forms

I would like to somehow load a JAR into a form element, and have it show up within the form, not as a separate entity. So the goal is to have a fully functioning java program working INSIDE of my VB.net program. :) As a complete fallback i will use the browser within vb.net to load the JAR, but i would very much prefer not to.

Hopefully that all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a bridge - now I don't know how these solutions pertain to the UI, but this search will get you started.

https://www.google.ca/search?q=java+.net+bridge

Comment: This is very interesting and is sorta what i was after, but my java application will not be interacting with my .net application at all. Which i believe is the use of these bridges, is mainly when the two programs needs to communicate. Do correct me if i am wrong though :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use IKVM,

http://www.ikvm.net/

As shown in its tutorial,

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ikvm/index.php?title=Tutorial

You can convert a jar to .NET assembly by executing `ikvmc your.jar`